# Inplace edit of a file using cstdio?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, cstdio

I have a file that I'm writing data to, using the functions in `cstdio`.  I want to make sure the file has successfully been written to file without any interruptions, so I know what to expect from the file when I later read from it.  The way I aim to do that, is by first writing 8 bytes worth of zeroed out data to the very beginning of the file, writing the file as normal, and then as a last step, rewinding the file and overwriting those first 8 bytes with a specific signature to denote that the file has been completed and well-formed.

My question is, what is the best way to edit those first 8 bytes in place?

With `fopen()`, what would be the appropriate opening mode (the second argument) to use?

Is it safe to just `rewind()` to the beginning and use `fwrite()`, or is there a specific function special to the act of overwriting?

Comment: FYI: Mode `"rb+"` will allow you to `fopen()` for read/write. And make sure if you immediately follow a `fwrite()` with an `fread()` you wedge a flush in between.

Comment: @whozCraig  That sounds about right, though I'm creating the file in this case.  Would "wb+" work similarly?

Comment: yes, that should be fine. It will truncate the file if it exists. If that is the intention, it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhozCraig is right. Using `wb+` is completely fine as well as `rewind` is.

You can also take a look at file locking, which ensures that:

- no one can read/write the file while you are holding exclusive lock
- no one can write the file while you are holding shared lock